# Codeigniter check existing username during update

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am new for codeigniter, now i am studying about CRUD operation, how can i check existing username in database without including the current session login username during update user, below is my update query

```
$this->db->select('username');
$this->db->from('form');
$this->db->where('username',$user);
$query = $this->db->get();
$num = $query->num_rows();
return $num;
```

Comment: you need atleast user_id or user_name of that user inorder to check username exists or not when updating

Comment: $user contain the username

Comment: public function username_check($user)
 {
  $this->db->select('username');
  $this->db->from('form');
  $this->db->where('username',$user);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $num = $query->num_rows();
  return $num;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$this->db->select('username');
$this->db->from('form');
$this->db->where('username',$user);
$this->db->where('user_id !=',$user_id); //user_id of the user
$query = $this->db->get();
$num = $query->num_rows();
return $num;
```